# My program is not ending when I’ve told it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to coding. 
So i am in the process of making a program and i have not quite finished it. But i have added an option where the program starts again if the user selects yes, if the user selects no the program should say good bye and stop. But when no is selected it says goodbye but starts the program again. Could someone tell me if im doing something wrong

When no is selected is starts the program again.

```
restart = True

while restart == True: 
    while True:
        print(' Welcome to My Program')
        print('Please Choose an Option')
        print('Option 1: Enter RLE')
        print('Option 2: Display ASCII Art')
        print('Option 3: Convert to ASCII Art')
        print('Option 4: Convert to RLE')
        print('Option 5: Quit')

        option = int(input('Choose an Option: '))


        if option ==1:
            Split=(list(input("Enter string: ")))
            Split.append("")
            a = 0
            for i in range(len(Split)):
                try:
                    if (Split[i] in Split) >0:
                        a = a + 1
                    if Split[i] != Split[i+1]:
                        print(Split[i],a)
                        a = 0

                except IndexError:
                    print()



        elif option == 2:
          print("Hello")

        elif option == 3:
          print("Hello")

        elif option == 4:
          print("Hello")

        elif option == 5:
          print ('Ending Program')
          exit()

        else:
          print('Invalid Input')

        while True:
            answer = str(input('Would You Like to Run The Program Again? (y/n): '))
            if answer in ('y', 'n'):
                break
            print ("Invalid input.")
        if answer == 'y':
            restart == True
        else:
            print ('Goodbye')
            restart == False
            break
```

When no is selected is starts the program again.

Comment: What do you think the `restart == False` line is doing? Is it different from the way you initialize `restart` at the beginning of the program?

Comment: Hint `=` and `==` are different.

Comment: Peter is right, you are doing a comparison where you would do an attribution. Change "restart == True" by "restart = True" and the same to the "False"

Answer (score 0):

The first `while True:` after `while restart == True:` has created an infinite loop. Try getting rid of that and just putting your program inside the first while loop.

Comment: He uses `break`s so that is technically not the issue. The issue is his misuse of `==` and `=` in the final `if` block.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much.